# npm scripts/package.json - run only if currently on git master branch

Tags: git, npm, npm-scripts

I'm trying to make a script that will only run if master is the currently checked out branch...

I managed getting the branch name with:

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

but putting that in a script, checking its value and doing one thing or other based on it is not going well

```
"foo": "set branch=git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD | if [branch==master]; then echo \"yes\"; else echo \"no\"; fi;"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following will work successfully:

**npm-script:**

```js
"scripts": {
  "foo": "branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD); if [[ $branch == \"master\" ]]; then echo \"yes\"; else echo \"no\"; fi;"
},
```

**Explanation:**

- The `git` command is wrapped in `$()` - which is known as [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). It means it will run the `git rev-parse ...` command and assign its output to the `branch` variable.
- Subsequently, a conditional check of the `branch` value is made by utilizing: `if [[ $branch == \"master\" ]]; then ...`

**Cross platform:**

This will obviously fail if the `npm run foo` command in executed in non Bash environments, such as Windows `cmd.exe` or *PowerShell*. If cross-platform support is a requirement, (which I'm guessing is not!), then I suggest handling this logic in a *node.js* script and utilize [`child_process.execSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) to invoke the `git` command. The `node.js` can then be invoked via your npm-script.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks so much RobC, that works perfectly :-)

Comment: @RobC for cross platform, how to then get output from the node.js and do conditional stuff like above in npm scripts?